# XSLT faster (= more efficient) grouping of rows

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xslt-1.0, grouping

Using XSLT to transform a CSV input into XML in two steps. After the first CSV-XML transform `csv2xml`, I'd like to group all elements belonging to the same row into one element where attributes are read from the first row (headers), ie.

**Initial (CSV) input**

```
<signature>
stroke,x,y,t
1,0.585,0.226,1460579160811
1,0.653,0.231,1460579160812
1,1.251,1.125,1460579160813
1,2.224,1.672,1460579160814
1,2.716,1.761,1460579160815
1,3.675,1.877,1460579160816
1,4.008,1.984,1460579160817
1,4.888,2.81,1460579160818
</signature>
```

**Output 1 (= Input 2)**

```
  <column row="1" col="1">stroke</column>
  <column row="1" col="2">x</column>
  <column row="1" col="3">y</column>
  <column row="1" col="4">t</column>
  <column row="2" col="1">1</column>
  <column row="2" col="2">0.585</column>
  <column row="2" col="3">0.226</column>
  <column row="2" col="4">1460579160811</column>
  <column row="3" col="1">1</column>
  <column row="3" col="2">0.653</column>
  <column row="3" col="3">0.231</column>
  <column row="3" col="4">1460579160812</column>
  <column row="4" col="1">1</column>
  <column row="4" col="2">1.251</column>
  <column row="4" col="3">1.125</column>
  <column row="4" col="4">1460579160813</column>
```

**Desired final output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<signature>
  <row stroke="1" x="0.585" y="0.226" t="1460579160811"/>
  <row stroke="1" x="0.653" y="0.231" t="1460579160812"/>
  <row stroke="1" x="1.251" y="1.125" t="1460579160813"/>
  <row stroke="1" x="2.224" y="1.672" t="1460579160814"/>
```

which I am achieving using the following XSLT template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
  version="1.0">
<xsl:strip-space elements="root"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
<!-- Version -->
<xsl:variable name="xslver" select='1' />

<xsl:template name="csv2xml">
  <xsl:param name="input" select="''"/>
  <xsl:param name="column" select="1"/>
  <xsl:param name="row" select="1"/>

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains(substring-before($input,','),'&#10;')">
      <xsl:element name="column">
        <xsl:attribute name="row">
          <xsl:value-of select="$row"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="col">
          <xsl:value-of select="$column"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($input,'&#10;')"/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:call-template name="csv2xml">
        <xsl:with-param name="input" select="substring-after($input,'&#10;')" />
        <xsl:with-param name="row" select="$row+1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="column" select="1"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="contains($input,',')">
      <xsl:element name="column">
        <xsl:attribute name="row">
          <xsl:value-of select="$row"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="col">
          <xsl:value-of select="$column"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($input,',')"/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:call-template name="csv2xml">
        <xsl:with-param name="input" select="substring-after($input,',')" />
        <xsl:with-param name="row" select="$row"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="column" select="$column + 1" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:element name="column">
        <xsl:attribute name="row">
          <xsl:value-of select="$row"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="col">
          <xsl:value-of select="$column"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="$input" />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="remap">
  <xsl:param name="input"/>
  <xsl:variable name="output">
    <xsl:call-template name="csv2xml">
      <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$input"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="csv" select="exsl:node-set($output)"/>

  <xsl:variable name="headers" select="$csv/column[@row=1]"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$csv/column[not(@row = following-sibling::column/@row)]">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="rows" select="$csv/column[@row=$pos]"/>
    <xsl:element name="row">
      <xsl:for-each select="$headers">
        <xsl:variable name="attr" select="text()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="pos2" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="{$attr}"><xsl:value-of select="$rows[@col=$pos2]/text()"/></xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:param name="root" value="'root'"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="trimmed">
    <xsl:call-template name="trim">
      <xsl:with-param name="input" select="*[local-name() = $root]"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:element name="{$root}">
    <xsl:call-template name="remap">
      <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$trimmed"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="trim">
  <xsl:param name="input" select="''"/>
  <xsl:variable name="out-rtrim">
    <xsl:call-template name="rtrim">
      <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$input"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="out-ltrim">
    <xsl:call-template name="ltrim">
      <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$out-rtrim"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="$out-ltrim"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="rtrim">
  <xsl:param name="input">&quot;</xsl:param>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string-length($input) &gt; 0">
      <xsl:variable name="first" select="substring($input,1,1)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="remainder" select="substring($input,2)"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length(normalize-space($first)) &gt; 0">
          <xsl:value-of select="$input"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:call-template name="rtrim">
            <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$remainder"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise/>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="ltrim">
  <xsl:param name="input">&quot;</xsl:param>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string-length($input) &gt; 0">
      <xsl:variable name="head" select="substring($input,1,string-length($input)-1)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="tail" select="substring($input,string-length($input),1)"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length(normalize-space($tail)) &gt; 0">
          <xsl:value-of select="$input"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:call-template name="ltrim">
            <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$head"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise/>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which works as expected, although not fast: xsltproc on an input of 500 rows takes roughly 1000ms, 98% of which is spent on the transform above, ie. step 2.

Is there any way to improve this? Perhaps by flattening the two `xsl:for-each`?

Comment: have you tried to run same transformation few times? probably it's just warm up phase takes so long.

Comment: I used the `--repeat` flag and it does take indeed ~ 1 s. per run.

Comment: `exsl:node-set($output)` isn't the reason either.

Comment: See: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks, interesting. But you can't define keys within a template apparently. I'd have to write another XSLT file which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: @okiharaherbst You define keys at the top level of your stylesheet, outside of any template. You do **not** need another XSLT document for this. -- P.S. There are many, many examples of Muenchian grouping here that you can use as your starting point - e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313339/how-do-i-select-unique-nodes-in-xslt-1-0-using-an-expression/22316125#22316125

Comment: @michael.hor257k It is my understanding that the key will generate a lookup register on the input XML. Here my input is a CSV file (`xsltproc csv2xml.xslt input.csv`) which is transformed twice within the same stylesheet, hence my remark. Or am I missing the point?

Comment: I am afraid this is too confusing. Your question shows XML as the input, and a large portion of your XSLT is missing. IMHO, the conversion of CSV to XML is irrelevant to the grouping problem. You cannot use XSLT for this step anyway. Once you have the input as XML, you can process it with XSLT. I believe you could do it in one pass, but even if not, there is no problem using Muenchian grouping (or keys in general) on a variable holding a node-set.

Comment: @michael.hor257k My mistake, I thought I'd simplify a little. Please see the edited question above with the actual source and why I thought that I cannot use the key as you kindly suggest in your answer. In the `remap` transform, the input2 is in the form of `exsl:node-set($output1)`. How can one use the key here without resorting to another xslt file?

Comment: This is s a completely different question. I would suggest a radically different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***-- edited in response to your clarification --***

Your cells are already grouped into rows in the input. Why don't you do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl str">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/signature">
    <!-- first pass: convert CSV to XML -->
    <xsl:variable name="table-rtf">
        <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(., '&#10;')">
            <row>
                <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(., ',')">
                    <col>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </col>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </row>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="table" select="exsl:node-set($table-rtf)"/>
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:variable name="header" select="$table/row[1]" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="$table/row[position() > 1]">
            <row> 
                <xsl:for-each select="col">
                    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
                    <xsl:attribute name="{$header/col[$i]}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </row> 
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is assuming your processor supports `str:tokenize()` - as libxslt does.

Comment: Many thanks, Michael. I wasn't aware of `str:tokenize()`, also available in exslt. The `key` pointer was also a good one though. I'd like to find out how to use it on a node-set however.

Comment: Here are two examples of that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892330/change-format-of-comma-delimited-tags-in-xml-using-xslt/21893239#21893239 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31393368/using-xslt-to-create-a-well-formatted-nested-table-from-unknown-xml/31417257#31417257